# 2 vlan connected with 2 internet connections

Tags: routes, vlan

I'm creating a new structural for the network of my company, but i'm stuck : i want to separate the two actual services : The call center and the navigation.

I got an SFR Box and a Freebox (French ISP's), i want to redirect the call center in the SFR (100Mbps), and the other on the Free(1000Mbps).
For this, i've created two Vlan on the Switch, VLAN10 f1-12 for the call, VLAN20 f13-24 for the navigation. Everything works fine already.

But i want to know : 
Can i use an internet connection per VLAN, or it will be any conflit when the routing? Obviously i will disable DHCP on each CPE, every computer will be on static.

Thanks :)

P.S.: For those who ask, i will match up the computers linked to the phones into the same Vlan.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case for policy-based routing. The router needs to be able to use both WAN links and route based on source VLAN/subnet.

For the central router to do its job you need to hide the WAN routers/CPEs from the LAN clients. Connect the WAN routers only to the central Router 1 and use the respective interface on Router 1 as client default gateway.